# JavaScript switch to change text and image

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a JavaScript function using switch to change the text within a `<div>`.  I have it working to just change text but I also want it to include HTML for an image.  What changes would I need to make to allow it to include the HTML code for the images?

```
<div id="languageText">
    This is the standard text <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> click the next image <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img></div>
</div>
```

```
function setIntroText(lang) {
  introText = document.getElementById('languageText');

  switch(lang) {
    case 'bg':
     introText = ("This is different text 1 " <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> "click the next image 1"  <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>);
      break;
    case 'hu':
      introText = ("This is different text 2 "  <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> "click the next image 2"  <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>);
      break;
    case 'ie':
      introText = ("This is different text 3"  <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> "click the next image 3"  <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>);
      break;
  } 
  document.getElementById("languageText").innerHTML = introText
}
```

Comment: Your html is false, please correct it and post a full snippet of your issue

Comment: You need to include the `<img>` tag in the text, i.e. between the quotes. Since you're also using quotes inside the tag, you need to either mask them or also use single quotes.

Comment: The [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Technical_summary) element has no closing `</img>` tag (`<img src="..." />`): _"Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag"_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work.
There is a problem on introText and you can cover it with quote('').
Now, when setting `innerText` value on switch clause, you have used several double-quotes("") on one line and that isn't accepted on javascript grammar.

So to assign one text to `innerText`, you need to bind those several strings(which is closed with double-quotes) with `+` symbol or, bind it with quote.

So these two cases are acceptable.

```
     introText = "This is different text 1 " + '<img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img>' + "click the next image 1" + '<img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>';
```

```
introText = 'This is different text 1 <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> click the next image 1 <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>';
```

The final codes are as follows.

```
function setIntroText(lang) {
  introText = document.getElementById('languageText');

  switch(lang) {
    case 'bg':
     introText = 'This is different text 1 <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> click the next image 1 <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>';
      break;
    case 'hu':
      introText = 'This is different text 2 <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> click the next image 2 <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>';
      break;
    case 'ie':
      introText = 'This is different text 3 <img src="image1.png" height="35px" ></img> click the next image 3 <img src="image2.png" height="30px"></img>';
      break;
  } 
  document.getElementById("languageText").innerHTML = introText
}
```

Comment: OP is obviously a beginner. So please explain the problem and _what_ you've changed and _why_.

Comment: The innerText you've set first will throw error because it does not follow the javascript code style.
on innerHTML, you should put html codes in text format.
And yours does not follow that. For example, you are using double-quote("") several times on one line and it does not work.

Comment: 1. I'm not OP, 2. add the explanation in your answer and not in a comment below that answer

Comment: Thanks everyone, Yes I am a javascript beginner and probably always will be lol. But using a combination of the edited code from Derek and the comment from Andreas I was able to see my mistake and make the changes to the code to get it working.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use JavaScript: [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp)
use `:target` selector